# close pcap file with scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I print all ipv6 of `file.pcap`

```
from scapy.all import *

scapy_cap = rdpcap('file.pcap')
for packet in scapy_cap:
    print packet[IPv6].src
```

How can I close this file handler after I finish to use it?  `rdpcap` read all the packet to RAM and I didn't find out how can I release that resource .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following piece should work

```
from scapy.all import *
scapy_cap = PcapReader('file.pcap').read_all()
for packet in scapy_cap:
    print packet[IPv6].src
scapy_cap.close()
```

Comment: What is the difference between  `rdpcap` and `PcapReader` ?

Comment: If you are looking for a more responsive code, consider using PcapReader() instead of rdpcap().

PcapReader() creates a generator and loads a packet only when it is needed, as opposed to rdpcap() which loads the entire trace into memory. PcapReader() is, therefore, well-suited for a large trace that takes forever to load with rdpcap(), or throws a MemoryError because it's simply too large for your system.